# Blank Column in the left part of the document

Tags: formatting

[image]

I would like to reproduce the code from the output shown in the picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, amsmath, textcomp, amsfonts,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry} %способ ручной установки полей
\geometry{top=2cm} %поле сверху
\geometry{bottom=2cm} %поле снизу
\geometry{left=3cm} %поле справа
\geometry{right=1cm} %поле слева
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Министерство образования и науки Российской Федерации\\
Федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего профессионального образования\\
Петрозаводский государственный университет (ПетрГУ)\\
Математический факультет\\

Кафедра информатики и математического обеспечения
\end{center}
\vbox{\vspace{1.3cm}}
\begin{center}
Промежуточный отчет о выполнении курсовой работы
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Анализ производительности беспроводной сети \\
802.11
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\vbox{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\begin{center}
\makebox[15em][l]{Выполнил:}\\
\makebox[15em][l]{студент 3 курса группы 22303 П. Г. Петров}
\end{center}
\vbox{\vspace{0.21cm}}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }

\begin{center}
\makebox[15em][l]{Научный руководитель:}\\
\makebox[15em][l]{к.ф.-м.н., доцент И.И.Петров}\\
\hbox to 12cm{Оценка руководителя: \hfil \rule{5cm}{0.5pt}}
\end{center}
\vbox{\vspace{0.5cm}}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\vspace{16mm}\noindent
\begin{center}
\makebox[15em][l]{Представлен на кафедру}\\ 
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
"\rule{0.9cm}{0.5pt}"\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} 2013 г.\\
\end{flushright}
\vspace{5mm}\noindent
\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{6.5cm}{
\hspace*{1cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись принявшего работу}}}\hspace*{-1cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}
\vspace{16mm}\noindent
\vspace{\fill}

\begin{center}
\Large
Петрозаводск

2013
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probabilly will be successfull by using `\leftskip=<some length>` right after the title.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \hbox{Выполнил:} \hbox{студент 3 курса группы 22303 П. Г. Петров}

\vbox{\hsize=8mm\vspace*{3mm}}

\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}
Научный руководитель: \зав. кафедрой ИМО, к.т.н.,\доцент Ю.~А.~Богоявленский\\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}
\vspace{4mm}\noindent

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by using a `minipage` to frame the content you wish to have pushed to the right.

In the following example, I've taken quite a few liberties with your code.  First, you have an odd mixture of LaTeX and TeX commands:  use `\mbox` instead of `\hbox`, use `\itshape` instead of `\it`.  I would recommend sticking with LaTeX:  it can achieve all the effect you want here.  You are also using several font *switches* as though they are macros that take an argument.  Commands for changing font sizes are `\small` and `\LARGE`.  If you want to delimite the range of their effect, you need to place them within a group.

Also I created a macro to handle the signature line.

Here's the MWE illustrate many of these changes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
%\voffset=-2.2mm
%\topmargin=-0.9in
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, amsmath, textcomp, amsfonts,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

%% #1 = width
%% #2 = subset dimen
%% #3 = title
\newcommand\subtitledline[3]{%%
  \hspace*{\fill}%%
  \hspace*{\dimexpr#1/2\relax}%%
  \makebox[0pt]{\raisebox{#2}{\small\itshape#3}}%%
  \hspace*{-\dimexpr#1/2\relax}%%
  \rule{#1}{0.4pt}
}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  Министерство образования и науки Российской Федерации\\
  Федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего профессионального образования\\
  Петрозаводский государственный университет (ПетрГУ)\\
  Математический факультет

  Кафедра информатики и математического обеспечения

  \vspace{1.3cm}

  Промежуточный отчет о выполнении курсовой работы

  {\LARGE
  Анализ производительности беспроводной сети \\
  802.11}
\end{center}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.6\linewidth}
  Выполнил:\\
  студент 3 курса группы 22303 П. Г. Петров

  \vspace*{1cm}

  \hspace*{\fill}\subtitledline{5cm}{-1em}{подпись}

  Научный руководитель: \\
  зав. кафедрой ИМО, к.т.н.,\\
  доцент Ю.~А.~Богоявленский
  \subtitledline{5cm}{-1em}{подпись}

  \vspace{1.25cm}

  \subtitledline{5cm}{-1em}{подпись}

  \vspace{16mm}

  Представлен на кафедру 
  \begin{flushright}
    "\rule{0.9cm}{0.5pt}"\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} 2013 г.
  \end{flushright}

  \vspace{5mm}

  \subtitledline{6.5cm}{-1em}{подпись принявшего работу}  
\end{minipage}
\vspace{17mm}
\begin{center}
\Large
Петрозаводск

2013
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, I would completely dispense with the `flushright` environments.  Since you're only applying to one line of text at a time, I would recommend using an `\hspace*{\fill}`:
This will, of course, mean that you'll have to adjust the vertical spaces around these *signature* lines.

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста в теме изоброжение    ... у мен проблы со строй "оценка руководителя "    все остальное я смог сделать

Comment: @SERGIY  I'm sorry, I don't read or speak Russian.

Comment: please see the image in the topic ... I have a problem with the system "assessment manager" everything else I could do

Answer (score 0):

What about `minipage`s?  If it is just a one-page thing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}           

\begin{center}             
\large WORDS  
\end{center}  

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth} 
\vspace{0pt}% empty minipage
\end{minipage}     
\hfill   
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}%
\lipsum[1] 
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not know what way the image is made
that the word "Petra"(Петров)is at the bottom line ?

Comment: @SERGIY -- Use: `\vfill                                                                          
\begin{center}
\Large
Петрозаводск\\                     
2013
\end{center}`.

Answer (score 0):

A corrected example. The precise values to be chosen:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\voffset=-2.2mm
\topmargin -0.9in
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, latexsym, amsmath, textcomp, amsfonts,mathtext,cite,enumerate,float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\textheight22cm % PS

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Министерство образования и науки Российской Федерации\\
Федеральное государственное бюджетное образовательное учреждение высшего профессионального образования\\
Петрозаводский государственный университет (ПетрГУ)\\
Математический факультет\\

Кафедра информатики и математического обеспечения
\end{center}
\vbox{\vspace{1.3cm}}
\begin{center}
Промежуточный отчет о выполнении курсовой работы
\end{center}
\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
Анализ производительности беспроводной сети \\
802.11
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\hspace*{0.29\textwidth}\begin{minipage}{0.71\textwidth} % PS

\hbox{Выполнил:} \hbox{студент 3 курса группы 22303 П. Г. Петров}

\vbox{\hsize=8mm\vspace*{3mm}}

\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}
Научный руководитель: \\
зав. кафедрой ИМО, к.т.н.,\\
доцент Ю.~А.~Богоявленский\\[7mm]
{Оценка руководителя:} \hrulefill
%\begin{flushright}
%\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
%\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
%\end{flushright}
\vspace{4mm}\noindent
\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}

\vspace{16mm}\noindent

Представлен на кафедру 
\begin{flushright}
"\rule{0.9cm}{0.5pt}"\rule{5cm}{0.5pt} 2013 г.\\
\end{flushright}
\vspace{5mm}\noindent
\begin{flushright}
\hfill\parbox{6.5cm}{
\hspace*{1cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись принявшего работу}}}\hspace*{-1cm}\hrulefill \\ }
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage} % PS


\vspace{16mm}\noindent
\vspace{\fill}

\begin{center}
\Large
Петрозаводск

2013
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: И как сделать, чтобы "весной (клей)" вот как       "Оценка руководеля         ____________________"

Comment: @SERGIY Do you want an additional text? Where? Somewhere between "Представлен на кафедру" and "подпись приниявшего работу"?

Comment: мне  нужно сделать  копию  этого документа  
http://kappa.cs.karelia.ru/p/Templates/interim/report/report.pdf
================
моя проблема  в  том что  я не понимаю  как мне   сделать  вот  такие вещи  как :
"\begin{center}
\makebox[15em][l]{Научный руководитель:}\\makebox[15em][l]{к.ф.-м.н., доцент И.И.Петров}\\end{center}
\makebox[15em][l]{Оценка руководителя:}\rule{5cm}{0.5pt}
\hfill\parbox{5cm}{
\hspace*{2cm}\hbox to 0cm{\raisebox{-1em}{\small{\it подпись}}}\hspace*{-2cm}\hrulefill \\ }"
получаеться не то  что  нужно  ... помогите   исправить это?
чтобы получилось  как  в /report.pdf

Comment: placed the image in the subject ... please see
I'm interested in how to do .... space and do not disrupt the speakers ....
namely, "Оценка руководителя: <space> _________"

Comment: У меня  получается вот  так ,  как исправить?              ![foto] (http://i.imgur.com/vetnMq5.png).

Comment: @SERGIY Please see my corrected solution. But I am still only guessing which elements (lengths etc.) are important.

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста   на мою  картинку   в теме    и сравните ее с вашим результатом  ...  вы увидите  что это не много не то  что  нужно МНЕ

Comment: у меня проблемы  со  строкой ,где написано  (Оценка руководителя)....  у меня получаеться что  строка смещаеться в лево

Comment: @SERGIY Новая версия :-)

Comment: yes=)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: `\vbox{\vspace{1.3cm}}`? I'm really surprised one can think to something like this: what should be the purpose?

Comment: @egreg How can I know? Mine are only the lines commented PS (And one additional, but I don't remember, which one).